# Thinkpad L460 freeze on startup

Tags: startup, 20.04, freeze, thinkpad

i have a thinkpad L460 plugged in with an usb3 Targus dockstation with dual boot installed (UBUNTU 20.04 / Windows 10).

Bios is up to date Version R08ET65W (1.39 )

When i boot the laptop for first attempt, it's freezing on the UBUNTU grey logo and i can't do anything, absolutely no response (esc, alt+ctrl+del...). I have to force the stop with start button.

on the second attempt, everything works fine.

I always have the same behavior whether the laptop is connected to the docking station or not.

**Edit**-the problem occurs when I restart the system with the restart function.
if I stop the system then I start again, everything is fine

Would someone have had the same kind of problem and have a solution to offer me?

Thanks